# android: own class extending activity and/or listactivity

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, listactivity

I have a couple of things which are the same in all my Activities throughout my application, e.g. an optionsmenu and some code which needs to run onresume, onrestart and onpause. I figured it would be a smart approach to put them in my a class MyListActivity extends ListActivity and then have all my activities extending MyListActivity.

This worked out just fine until I created an activity which didn't have a ListView. the App crashes because ListActivity expects a ListView. However, this new activity does not need a ListView, but would still need all my functions / Overrides in MyListActivity .

Right now I can think of two solutions. One: add a dummy listview to the layout with visibility = false, height & width = 0 (haven't tried this, but i guess it should work). And Two: copy/paste the contents of the MyListActivity class into a MyActivity extends Activity class. I feel very silly doing this, but I don't have any other ideas on how to solve this issue.

Any ideas on how to handle this nicer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can implement all the features in an `Activity` subclass (e.g., `MyActivity`) and make the `MyListActivity` class a subclass of the `MyActivity` class.

Other approach is to make a helper class which contains all the features in static methods with an `Activity` object as the first argument. In this case you don't need to create `MyActivity` or `MyListActivity` classes, but you need to call methods of the helper class in every `Activity` subclass you want to inherit these features.

Comment: right, these helper classes are very very useful in android, because you have to do the same tasks in multiple activities

Comment: i can't see your first solution working. If I have MyActivity extends Activity, and then MyListActivity extends Activity, I don't have the actual ListActivity inherited in MyListActivity. I tried making a helper class, but it's not very neat either. E.g. i have to pass my Application class aswell if I want to use any of it's functions. But it's probably the only way ...

Comment: In the first solution you need to inherit `MyListActivity` from `MyActivity` adding all the functionality from `ListActivity` class to `MyListActivity`. I'm pretty sure `ListActicity` is rather simple. And I didn't get the idea about `Application`. Can you explain more precisely?

Comment: And you should really make MyListActivity abstract.